# jquery.min.js, footable.min.js, jquery-1.9.1.js and jquery-ui.js does not work together

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, gridview, jquery-ui-autocomplete

> In following code there is both **autocomplete** and **Bootrap 3.0 Gridview Footable** both operation in a same page of aspx but the doesnt work.
>   If both of them one is included in page then it will work only one that is **gridview footable** or **autocomplete**.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/webshim/1.14.5/polyfiller.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/Date.js"></script>
<script src="../javascripts/AutoComplete/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="../javascripts/AutoComplete/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="../stylesheets/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../stylesheets/Loginmodel.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad(sender, args) {
        $(function () {
            $('#<%=txtSearch.ClientID%>').autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "StudReg.aspx/GetStudentName",
                        data: "{ 'pre':'" + request.term + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                                return { value: item }
                            }))
                        },
                        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert(textStatus);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    }
</script>
<%--  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function CopyText() {
        var txt2 = document.getElementById("<%= this.txtPermanentAddress.ClientID %>");
        txt2.value = document.getElementById("<%= this.txtTemporaryAddress.ClientID %>").value;
    }
</script>--%>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Confirm() {
        var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
        confirm_value.type = "hidden";
        confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
        if (confirm("Do you want to Delete data?")) {
            confirm_value.value = "Yes";
        } else {
            confirm_value.value = "No";
        }
        document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
    }
</script>
<style>
    .required:first-letter {
        color: red;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
<script src="../Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../stylesheets/Gridview%20footable/footable.min.js"></script>
<script>

    function pageLoad() {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(function () {
                $('[id*=gvSearchStudent]').footable();

            });
        });
    }
    //$(function () {
    //    $('[id*=gvEmployee]').footable();
    //});
</script>
```

> Please give me a solution for it.
>   footable-min.js is used for responsive design of Gridview and Autocomplete is used for displaying a reletive list with text type in textbox.

Comment: open your browser console and what errors are there!!

Comment: Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher(anonymous function) @ bootstrap.min.js:6(anonymous function) @ bootstrap.min.js:6

Comment: `<script src="../Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>`, `<script src="../javascripts/AutoComplete/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>` remove these line

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: s is not defined(anonymous function) @ jquery.min.js:2

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).superfish is not a function(anonymous function) @ responsivemenu.js:3l @ foundation.min.js:18c.fireWith @ foundation.min.js:18v.extend.ready @ foundation.min.js:18A @ foundation.min.js:18

Comment: as far i can see from here , the issue is multiple jquery instances and plugin order. try to remove all other jquery script tags and add every plugin at a same place

Comment: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null
e.run @ foundation.min.js:46
(anonymous function) @ foundation.min.js:46
h @ foundation.min.js:46

Comment: I have used both master page and content page, In master page also give a different link and script of other .js and .css

Comment: After removing <script src="../Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>, <script src="../javascripts/AutoComplete/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>  not working both